# Make CSS classes styled in WYSIWYG

Tags: wysiwyg

How can I make CSS classes that can be added to content in a WYSIWYG style in the edit view?

I've added the following 'CSS classes' and I've used my site's normal CSS to float them left and right respectively and give them a width of 51%:

```
Left=div.posLeft
Right=div.posRight
```

When I save the node this works fine. However in the editor the styles are not shown. How can I make them show up?

Comment: In the WYSIWYG configuration you can tell it what CSS files to use _within_ the editor. You simly create a CSS file with the rules needed. I know this works for wysiwyg+ckeditor, i'm uncertain what editor you're using ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @tenken says, on the WYSIWYG profile edit page, under the 'CSS' panel, in the 'CSS path' filed you can link to a CSS file to be used on the edit view.

/admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/PROFILE-NAME/edit